# Aggregate time series data by duration in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, time-series, aggregate

I am trying to migrate an InfluxDB query to Google Cloud BigQuery.

InfluxDB is a time series database, so aggregation by time intervals is very easy. Given this dataset:

```
name: h2o_feet
--------------
time                   water_level   location
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   8.12          coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   2.064         santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z   8.005         coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z   2.116         santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z   7.887         coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z   2.028         santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:18:00Z   7.762         coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:18:00Z   2.126         santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:24:00Z   7.635         coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:24:00Z   2.041         santa_monica
2015-08-18T00:30:00Z   7.5           coyote_creek
2015-08-18T00:30:00Z   2.051         santa_monica
```

The query below groups query results into 12 minute intervals:

```
SELECT COUNT("water_level") FROM "h2o_feet" WHERE "location"='coyote_creek' AND time >= '2015-08-18T00:00:00Z' AND time <= '2015-08-18T00:30:00Z' GROUP BY time(12m)

name: h2o_feet
--------------
time                   count
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   2
2015-08-18T00:12:00Z   2
2015-08-18T00:24:00Z   2
```

Does anyone know if there is a direct equivalent of the `GROUP BY time(12m)` part in BigQuery?

Laurent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in BigQuery but you can submit feature request in [`Issue Tracker`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100182)

Meantime, below is what I would consider as workaround

> Option 1

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT MIN(time) time, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.h2o_feet`
WHERE location = 'coyote_creek' 
AND time BETWEEN '2015-08-18T00:00:00' AND '2015-08-18T00:30:00'
GROUP BY DIV(DATETIME_DIFF(time, '2015-08-18T00:00:00', MINUTE), 12)
```

> Option 2

more wordy version (not sure really why I would use below option over first one  - but for the sake of experimenting with code maybe)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH start_finish AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:00:00' start, DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:30:00' finish, DATETIME '2000-01-01T00:00:00' base
), intervals AS (
  SELECT pos1, pos2,
    DATETIME_ADD(base, INTERVAL start_interval MINUTE) start,
    DATETIME_ADD(base, INTERVAL finish_interval MINUTE) finish
  FROM (
    SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(start, base, MINUTE) start,
      DATETIME_DIFF(finish, base, MINUTE) finish,
      base
    FROM start_finish
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start, finish, 12)) start_interval WITH OFFSET pos1,
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start, finish + 12, 12)) finish_interval WITH OFFSET pos2
  WHERE pos1 = pos2 - 1 
)
SELECT start, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.h2o_feet`
JOIN intervals
ON time >= start AND time < finish
WHERE location = 'coyote_creek' 
GROUP BY start
```

In `start_finish` CTE you just need to set `start` and `finish` time - the rest is done by rest of query

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.h2o_feet` AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:00:00' time, 8.12 water_level, 'coyote_creek' location UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:00:00', 2.064, 'santa_monica' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:06:00', 8.005, 'coyote_creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:06:00', 2.116, 'santa_monica' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:12:00', 7.887, 'coyote_creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:12:00', 2.028, 'santa_monica' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:18:00', 7.762, 'coyote_creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:18:00', 2.126, 'santa_monica' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:24:00', 7.635, 'coyote_creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:24:00', 2.041, 'santa_monica' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:30:00', 7.5, 'coyote_creek' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:30:00', 2.051, 'santa_monica' 
), start_finish AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:00:00' start, DATETIME '2015-08-18T00:30:00' finish, DATETIME '2000-01-01T00:00:00' base
), intervals AS (
  SELECT pos1, pos2,
    DATETIME_ADD(base, INTERVAL start_interval MINUTE) start,
    DATETIME_ADD(base, INTERVAL finish_interval MINUTE) finish
  FROM (
    SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(start, base, MINUTE) start,
      DATETIME_DIFF(finish, base, MINUTE) finish,
      base
    FROM start_finish
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start, finish, 12)) start_interval WITH OFFSET pos1,
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(start, finish + 12, 12)) finish_interval WITH OFFSET pos2
  WHERE pos1 = pos2 - 1 
)
SELECT start, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.h2o_feet`
JOIN intervals
ON time >= start AND time < finish
WHERE location = 'coyote_creek' 
GROUP BY start
-- ORDER BY start
```

Both versions produce below result

```sql
Row     start                   cnt  
1       2015-08-18T00:00:00     2    
2       2015-08-18T00:12:00     2    
3       2015-08-18T00:24:00     2
```

> Option 3 - (silly one - but to make it look similar to GROUP BY time(12m) and the original query from question

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION duration(time DATETIME) AS ((
  DIV(DATETIME_DIFF(time, '2015-08-18T00:00:00', MINUTE), 12)
));
SELECT MIN(time) time, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.h2o_feet`
WHERE location = 'coyote_creek' 
AND time BETWEEN '2015-08-18T00:00:00' AND '2015-08-18T00:30:00'
GROUP BY duration(time)
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Mikhail. Option 1 works like a charm and I learned a lot from the other ones. Thanks for the [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) extension too!

Comment: Also, great to hear you are using BQ Mate - thank you! :o)